# C#/DataTable - Getting datable first row & last row value base on the column value

Tags: c#, datatable, datatables

I want to get the first row & last row of the DataTable base on the column value.

```
StoreNo   ORNo
1         AAA
2         BBB
1         CCC
2         DDD
1         EEE
2         FFF
```

I want to get the **AAA** & **EEE** because it is the first and last **ORNo** of the **StoreNo**

*This is my code:*

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     if (dataTable.Rows[i]["StoreNo"].ToString().Equals("1"))
        {
            firstID = dataTable.Rows[0]["ORNo"].ToString();
        }
     if (dataTable.Rows[i]["StoreNo"].ToString().Equals("1"))
        {
            lastID = dataTable.Rows[dataTable.Rows.Count - 1]["ORNo"].ToString();
        }
 }
```

I always get **AAA** & **FFF**.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `dataTable.Rows[dataTable.Rows.Count - 1]`, you want `dataTable.Rows[i]` (same for firstID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linq instead of for loop,

Before you begin, make sure that the following lines are at the top of your code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

then try this code,

```
var list = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row["StoreNo"].ToString() == "1");
firstID = list.FirstOrDefault()["ORNo"];
lastID = list.LastOrDefault()["ORNo"];
```

Comment: Just a note: Your code will throw a NullReferenceException if none of the rows has StoreNo=1.

Comment: Thanks for your warning I fixed it to "1"

Comment: I did not mean this, but: if none of the rows satisfies the Where condition, `FirstOrDefault`/ `LastOrDefault` will return `null`.

Comment: Thank you @MustafaTarım but I'm getting an error `The type arguments for method 'DataRowExtensions.Field<T>(DataRow, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but anyway my 2 cents.

Your code doesn't work because you are **always** assigning `Rows[0]` and the last row, regardless of the value in `StoreNo`. Note that what you assign is not even using `i`.

If you want *old school* approach, you can do like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataTable.Rows[i]["StoreNo"].ToString().Equals("1"))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstID))
            lastID = firstID = dataTable.Rows[i]["ORNo"].ToString();
        else
            lastID = dataTable.Rows[i]["ORNo"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This way with the first 1 you get both assigned (in case it's the only appearance). And then, with each case you update the last one.